# cakePHP model update issue

Tags: cakephp, model

I've been runing on my issue all night long tried many method to update an entry of User model and I didn't figure it out.

I tried with saveField, updateAll and findBy then save but all i've got is new entry on my DB or no update.

Here is the code, Hope you'll help

```
    <?php
    public function email_verification($token) {
    $this->User->create();
    $user = $this->User->findByEmailToken($token);
    $this->User->set(array('email_token' => 'valid'), $user);
    $this->User->save($user, false);
}
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahum:

```
$this->User->set(array('email_token' => 'valid'), $user);
$this->User->save($user, false);
```

The save() call saves your record with your **original** data..... since you pass in $user!

Replace the call to $this->user->set() with:

```
$user['User']['email_token'] => 'valid';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
<?php
public function email_verification($token) {
    $user = $this->User->findByEmailToken($token);
    $user['User']['email_token'] = 'valid';
    if ($this->User->save($user)) {
        ....
        ....
    } else {
        debug($this->User->validationErrors);
    }
}
?>
```